# Issue with Self join statement php

Tags: php, mysqli, self-join

Here is the line

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM PMOrder a, PMList b where AssetNum= b.'$AssetNum';";
```

I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''PQ0000357'' at line 1

I'm assuming I can do a select a from both tables and echo the results as needed or do I need to pull all the columns from both? first time using the self join.
 A explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance 
Corrected code

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM PMOrder a, PMList b where b.AssetNum= '$AssetNum';";
```

Comment: `b.'$AssetNum'`? What is this?

Comment: I pull the $AssetNum it is in both tables. That's the PQ0000357 Its correctly getting the value of $AssetNum

Comment: If you have phpmyadmin installed on your server, you can test run your sql query [on there](https://www.siteground.com/img/knox/tutorials/uploaded_images/images/phpmyadmin/33.jpg)

Comment: Thank you StefansArya. Didn't even think about that. Got it working!